# How to trigger override methods after button press?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, overriding

I want to Override `onBackPressed()` but after onClick event.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Toast Please wait for process
}
```

This is my onClick method: I want to Override `onBackPressed()` only if this method executes.

```
private void fetchData() {
    showLoader();
}
```

Comment: add some global flag `boolean overrideBackPress = false;`, then in onClick set it to true, and in `onBackPressed` do `if(overrideBackPress) { <do whatever you need>} else { super.onBackPressed()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **keep a boolean variable** and update its value to true when your fetchData method finished executing and in your `onBackPressed()` method you can check the value of that boolean variable and execute your code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use below snippet.

```
   boolean flag=false;
    ...

    private void fetchData() {
       showLoader();
       flag=true;
    } 
    ...

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
      if(flag){
          //Toast Please wait for process
      }else{
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }
```

Once your process is completed make flag=false; so it will have normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code snippet that you can use :

    boolean isClicked=false;
     void buttonClick(){
     isclicked=true
    //you rest of the code 
    }
   @override
   void onBackpressed(){
   if(isclicked){
  //your click logic 
   }else{
  super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

thus you can simply use on method as two different method by using that flag

Answer (score 0):

you have to code like below:

```
private boolean isDataCalled = true; // global variable
```

Then

```
private void fetchData() {
    isDataCalled = false;
    showLoader();
}
```

When your data completely loaded make this variable true.

```
isDataCalled = true;
```

In you onBackPress method:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isDataCalled) {
        super.onBackPressed(); // back press when no data fething.
    } else {
        //Toast Please wait for process
    }
}
```